# Output the Search Cursor as a string

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I am trying to select Zones that intersect the dataframe (polygon). 
If there is only one return then I want to turn it into a sting. 
If there is multiple I want to turn  it into a string with " ," (space then comma) in between each.

My code is as follow:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(ZoneSHP, "ZoneLYR")
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("ZoneLYR", "INTERSECT", "polygon"):
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(ZoneLYR, "Zone") as cursor:
    int(arcpy.GetCount_management(ZoneLYR).getOutput(0))
    if getOutput == 1:
            Zone = row[]
    else:
        for row in curser:
            zone1 = ", " + row[]
        Zone = zone1[3:]
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code snippet that you provided?  I think you should include any error thrown as an **edit** to your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue I see is that you are not assigning your count to a variable. Also, `row[]` isn't correct syntax. And you're missing a `for row in cursor:`. And you spell cursor wrong in a spot. And you have a colon where you shouldn't in your select by location code. And your logic for combining zone values doesn't quite work.

Try this:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(ZoneSHP, "ZoneLYR")
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("ZoneLYR", "INTERSECT", "polygon")
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(ZoneLYR, "Zone") as cursor:
    outPut = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(ZoneLYR).getOutput(0))
    if outPut == 1:
        for row in cursor:
            Zone = row[0]
    else:
        Zone = ""
        for row in cursor:
            if Zone:
                Zone = Zone + ", " + row[0]
            else:
                Zone = row[0]
```

Or maybe even better:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(ZoneSHP, "ZoneLYR")
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("ZoneLYR", "INTERSECT", "polygon")
zones = [r[0] for r in arcpy.da.SearchCursor ("ZoneLYR", "Zone")]

Zone = ", ".join (zones)
```